# Ruby: Condition as a variable does not work

Tags: ruby, loops, conditional-statements

Just started learning looping and flow control in Ruby and got stuck with this exercise. I've been testing and searching for answers but did not find any so I'm posting here.

If I have my code setup like this:

```
ask_play = ''
loop do
    print "Play?: "
    ask_play = gets.chomp
    break if (ask_play == 'n') || (ask_play == 'N')
end
```

Then I exit out of the loop after entering n or N.

However, if I have my code setup like this:

```
ask_play = ''
play_stop = (ask_play == 'n') || (ask_play == 'N')
loop do
    print "Play?: "
    ask_play = gets.chomp
    break if play_stop
end
```

The condition does not seem to work. I still keep on looping even after typing in n or N and I'm just puzzled why.

Comment: Hint #1: What is the value of `ask_play` at line 2? Hint #2: it gets assigned in line 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`play_stop = (ask_play == 'n') || (ask_play == 'N')` gets evaluated before the loop begins. It sets the `play_stop` variable to `false` because the `ask_play` variable that you assigned to an empty string is neither `n` nor `N`.
It looks like you want to encapsulate the logic of the condition. You can create a method and pass a value to it.

```rb
def play_stop(input)
  input == 'n' || input == 'N'
end

loop do
    print "Play?: "
    ask_play = gets.chomp
    break if play_stop(ask_play)
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. My logic now works after placing my condition in a method. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Proc.html) to encapsulate the condition:

```
ask_play = ''
play_stop = -> { ask_play == 'n' || ask_play == 'N' }

loop do
  print "Play?: "
  ask_play = gets.chomp
  break if play_stop.call
end
```

You could also *pass* the string to the proc instead of referring to the local variable:

```
play_stop = -> (s) { s == 'n' || s == 'N' }

loop do
  print "Play?: "
  break if play_stop.call(gets.chomp)
end
```

Procs also work nicely in `case` statements:

```
play_stop = -> (s) { s == 'n' || s == 'N' }

loop do
  print "Play?: "
  case gets.chomp
  when play_stop
    break
  end
end
```